# Invoke pytest function as subprocess

Tags: python, pytest

Need suggestions/pointers on how do I write a wrapper script to perform following stuff.

1. Execute multiple test functions from given script which is written based on pytest.

**test_no1.py**

```
  def test_sum():
    return (a+b)
  def test_multiply():
    return (a*b)
```

**test_no2.py**

```
def test_sub():
  return(a-b)
def test_div():
  return (a/b)
```

In pytest, we can execute this as
***$> pytest test_no1.py::test_sum test_no2.py::test_sub***
How do I invoke this as a subprocess in pytest?

2. Create a single instance of logger from wrapper script and capture the execution of both above functions into it.
3. The execution of these functions should happen in serial way (one after the other) & with timeout.